# Alternative to session variable in my scenario

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a miniview which pops out and popsin on user click. It has to retain its state between pages. If user opens the miniview and goto another page and comeback, it should be open.I have done this using session variable.. the code is:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Session["miniviewstatus"]" id="miniviewstatus" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(".pullout_ico").click(function() {
        var url = "/StudentInformation/getminiviewstatus";
        $.post(url, { status: "true" }, function (data) {
            openMiniView();
        });
    });
    $(".pullout_button").click(function() {
        var url = "/StudentInformation/getminiviewstatus";
        $.post(url, { status: "false" }, function (data) {
            closeMiniView();
        });

    });
    var status = $("#miniviewstatus").val();
    if (status == "true") {
        openMiniView();
    }
    if (status == "false") {
        closeMiniView();
    }
    function openMiniView() {
            $(".pullout_block").show(250);
            $(".pullout_ico").hide(100);
            $(".left_content").removeClass("bigger_left_content");
    }
    function closeMiniView() {
            $(".pullout_ico").show(100);
            $(".pullout_block").hide(250);
            $(".left_content").addClass("bigger_left_content");
    }
};
```

studentinformation controller has basically getminiviewstatus which sets string value. Now,it works fine, but I dont like this way. Is there anyway, I can store status between dom loads??

Comment: seems alright. The only thing I can think of is to use simple browser  cookies and get rid of the server dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ravi answers in the comment, cookies are a good solution when using js and doing things on the client side. To give a little more detail, I would use the [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin to get and set the cookie. I would then change your code to the following, and eliminate the server side support for your ajax actions.

```
$(".pullout_ico").click(function() {
    $.cookie("miniviewstatus", true);
});
$(".pullout_button").click(function() {
    $.cookie("miniviewstatus", false);
});

var status = $.cookie("miniviewstatus");
if (status) {
    openMiniView();
} else {
    closeMiniView();
}

function openMiniView() {
    $(".pullout_block").show(250);
    $(".pullout_ico").hide(100);
    $(".left_content").removeClass("bigger_left_content");
}

function closeMiniView() {
    $(".pullout_ico").show(100);
    $(".pullout_block").hide(250);
    $(".left_content").addClass("bigger_left_content");
}
```